# matlab - 2 second degree ODE plot with runge kutta - numerical methods

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-methods, ode

The following equation is given.

[image]

I know that i need to break the 2 second order ODE's into 4 first order ODE's. This i what i've got. Ive first introduced the new variable u and in the bottom of the picture i've written my matlab function that i use with ODE45.

[image]

Now the problem is that im supposed to get a parabola shaped figure(blue line) but that is not what I am getting.

[image]

I've gone through my code a thousand times with no results. Can detect any errors in my function?

**main program**

```
global g H R alfa 
alfa=pi/2;
g = 20.0;
R = 1;
H=2.3;
k = 0:0.01:2;
[T,Y] = ode45(@fspace,k,[H 0 0 0]);
plot(T,Y(:,1))
hold on 


fi= 0:2*pi/60:2*pi;
xx =R*cos(fi);
yy =R*sin(fi);
plot(xx,yy)
```

**function f**

```
function f = fspace(x,u)
global g R H alfa G
G=(g*R.^2)./((R+H).^2);
f = [u(2) G*cos(alfa)-g*((R.^2)/u(1).^2)+u(1)*u(4)^2 u(4) (G*sin(alfa)-2*u(2)*u(4))/u(1)];
```

Comment: is your question matlab related at all? if yes, you need to post the relevant matlab code. otherwise your question is not suitable for SO, rather it should be moved to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: it is matlab realted. The function is written in matlab code.

Comment: These are two coupled non-linear ODEs; the 2nd term in each equation makes it so.  You have to solve these in iterative, incremental fashion.  You have to linearize these first.

Comment: But isn't that what im doing when i use ODE45? And it says in the problem description to use ODE45 to solve the equation.

Comment: Show us your actual MATLAB code, both the function and how you call the `ode45` solver, not just a picture of a mathematical equation.

Comment: Ive added the matlab code now! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies with those lines:

```
fi= 0:2*pi/60:2*pi;
xx =R*cos(fi);
yy =R*sin(fi);
plot(xx,yy)
```

You are plotting a circle of radius `R`. `phi` is part of the solution from the `ode` solver, so you should have instead:

```
plot(R*cos(Y(:,3)),R*sin(Y(:,3)))
```

but that will always give you a circle of radius `R`, never a parabola. Or is the parabola meant to refer to `plot(T,Y(:,1))`.

The equations and the code appear to be correct as far as I can see. Replacing your definition of `phi` by `Y(:,3)` gives essentially the same plot, except that the resolution is less.  As I said, you'll always get a circle by plotting `yy` vs `xx`. You need to clarify what the parabola should refer to.

[image]

Comment: Its not the circle what is supposed to be a parabola. Its the other plot!

Comment: Well, I've double-checked the equations and the MATLAB code and they're both correct, so either the initial differential equations are wrong or your expectation of a parabola is wrong.

Comment: The system is in polar coordinates (what is the system in Cartesian coordinates?) with `r=y(1)` and `phi=y(3)`. Thus `cart_x=Y(:,1).*cos(Y(:,3))` and `cart_y=Y(:,1).*sin(Y(:,3))`

Comment: @LutzL It looks like the OP is expecting `r(t)` to be a parabola. Not sure why or where that comes from...

Comment: The system seems to describe an active object in a gravitational field. Thrust is `G·cos(α)` away from the center and `G·sin(α)` orthogonal to that, i.e., `G` at an angle `α` to the radial vector. It should at least look physically plausible.